# Populate a Custom drop down box in Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am trying to populate a drop-down box which I have created in the Data-Tables plug-in for JQuery.
The code I have used is:

```
var oTable = $('#reqAllQueriesTable')
.dataTable(
{
 "sDom": '<"H"<"tools">lfrt>',
});
$("div.tools").html('Organize by Teams: <select id="booking_status"><option value="">Teams</option><option value="team1">Team 1</option><option value="team2">Team 2</option></select>');
```

I want to replace the static contents of `select` in HTML by the content by a `List` of objects in my Java code.
Is this possible by replacing the existing code? If yes, how can the Java object be used in this code.
Please help.

Comment: you can echo entire javascript via out.println , and imbibe your JDBC code in select statement

Comment: i did not get what exactly you mean to say. can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.
I pass a model attribute from my java code which calls the JSP:

```
model.addAttribute("userTeams",userTeams);
```

Then in jQuery Data Table, I overwrite the DOM to call a `div` named `myTools`:

```
var oTable = $('#reqAllQueriesTable')
.dataTable(
{
 "sDom": '<"H"<"myTools">lfrt>',
});
```

The div which creates the drop-down list looks like:

```
$("div.myTools").html('Organize by Teams: <select id="teams"><option value="">Team</option><c:forEach var="userTeams" items="${userProjectTeams}"><option value="${userTeams.teamId}" onClick="javascript:takeAction(this.value)"> ${userTeams.teamtName}</option></c:forEach></select>');
```