# Custom jQuery Data Table column search function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatable

I have created a custom header on a J-Query data table using the code you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312302/populate-a-custom-drop-down-box-in-data-table).
I want to add a custom parameter to the data table when a particular item from the drop-down box is selected.

Following is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var oTable = $('#reqAllQueriesTable')
    .dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "query/getQuery",
      "bFilter": true,
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sSearch": "Search",
      "sDom": '<"H"<"projectTeamTools">lrft>'
    });

  $("div.projectTeamTools").html('Organize by Project Teams: <select id="projectTeams"><option value="1">Project Team</option><c:forEach var="projectTeam" items="${userProjectTeams}"><option value="${projectTeam.projectId}" onClick="javascript:onTeamSelect(this.value)">${projectTeam.projectName}</option></c:forEach></select>');
});

function onTeamSelect(teamId) {
  alert(teamId + " Selected");
  oTable.aoServerParams.push({
    name: "aoTeamId",
    value: teamId
  }); //This line does not work.
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="reqAllQueriesTable"></table>
```

The `onTeamSelect()` function gets called properly and the alert is displayed. But I want to add the custm parameter `aoTeamId` to the data table and pass the value to the `getQuery` controller I am using to populate the data-table. Is this possible? Please help!